# dll library with cpprestsdk compilation on windows xp

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll, windows-xp, cpprest-sdk

I have dll project using cpprestsdk in visual studio 2019 (along with console application for testing purposes).
On windows 7 and windows 10 original package works as expected, however I'm having hard time to compile and run on windows XP.

cpprestsdk is included in the project through NuGet, version: `cpprestsdk.v141` but, its not visible for the compiler. Line `#include <cpprest/http_client.h>` throws an error.

Changes i've made:

- platform toolset set to `Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)`
- preprocessor definitions updated to include `CPPREST_TARGET_XP`
- statically included `cpprest141_2_10.dll`
- statically linked `cpprest141_2_10.lib`
- console application setting `ConformanceMode` set to `false`

Now the app is compiling, but it's not working properly on windows 10 (crashes on sending request). and it's not starting on windows XP (dll entry point not found)

Any1 have any idea what's going on?

@edit:
after adding to program folder missing dlls:

- `api-ms-win-core-crt-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-crt-l2-1-0.dll`
- `httpapi.dll`

it came to `ntdll.dll`

[Entry Point Not Found error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcHOx.png)

`The procedure entry point WinSqmAddToStreamEx could not be located in the dynamic link library ntdll.dll`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you sure the DLLs themselves were built for XP? Perhaps there is a different DLL for that platform and toolset? Could you build the DLLs yourself to make sure everything matches?

Comment: @Michał Mach - If you will add a detailed description of the error to the post it can help to understand the picture clearer.

Comment: 1st of all *XP* is no longer supported by *MS*. Also is the pkg supposed to build for *XP*?

Comment: Yes, I know, but the dll it meant for XP POS Embedded (EOL 2019). Sadly there is no way around, it has to work for XP.
The cpprestsdk package should build for XP, I've tried to build from v2.9.1 tag https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/tree/v2.9.1/Release/src/build/vs14.xp
But still no luck (XP still screams about missing dlls / missing entry points in dlls)

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is downgrade your Visual studio to 2013 and donwload the version of cpprest SDK like 2.9.1 which support the VS 2013 (msvc 120) as well, hope it helps